# Need some help how to make a click to copy using javascript

Tags: javascript

//here is my html code for the button

```HTML
<html>
  <div class="newpassword">
    <div class="square" id="password-el"></div>
    <button id="copy-pass">Copy</button>
    <div class="square" id="passwordTwo-el"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

//here's my javascript code

```
let characters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","{","[","}","]",",","|",":",";","<",">",".","?","/"];
    
let passwordEl       = document.getElementById("password-el");
let passwordTwoEl    = document.getElementById("passwordTwo-el")
let generatePassword = document.getElementById("btn");
let copyOne          = document.getElementById("copy-pass")
    
let passwordLength = 16;
    
generatePassword.addEventListener("click", function() {
  function getRandomNum() {
    let randomChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    return characters[randomChar];
  }
    
  function generateRandomPass() {
    let randomPass = ""
    for(let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++ ){
      randomPass += getRandomNum()
    }
    return randomPass;
  }
    
  let newPassOne = generateRandomPass();
  let newPassTwo = generateRandomPass();
    
  passwordEl.textContent    = newPassOne;
  passwordTwoEl.textContent = newPassTwo;
});
    
copyOne.onclick = function() {
  passwordEl.select();
   
  document.execCommand("Copy");
};
```

Comment: The `execCommand` method on the `Document` object [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) and should not be used. Instead use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to copy to the clipboard in javascript:

```
copyOne.onclick = function() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(passwordEl.textContent);
};
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard for more info on the api

Comment: Hello I just want to ask what's the difference if I will just add "onclick="toggle" function on HTML button. 

Then on JS

function toggle(){
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(passwordEl.textContent);
} *which this didn't work

Comment: putting javascript functions directly in the HTML is not how most of us do it these days. typically we add event listeners via `copyOne.addEventListener('click', toggle)`. If you want to do it via the attribute, you need to add the parenthesis. So it would be `onclick="toggle()"`.

Comment: I really appreciate it! Seems I'm following an outdated course. Is there anything you can recommend that I can follow ?